# Lollipop: Disabled button --> which style?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

I tried to track down, how **Lollipop** displays a button, which is disabled with `android:enabled="false"` in the layout file.

### Holo

With **Holo**, it's easy: In the styles_holo.xml, I find the style Widget.Holo.Button, which gives me a reference to @drawable/btn_default_holo_dark. There I find the selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true"
android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal_holo_dark" />
<item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="false"
android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_disabled_holo_dark" />
<item android:state_pressed="true"
android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_pressed_holo_dark" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="true"
android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_focused_holo_dark" />
<item android:state_enabled="true"
android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal_holo_dark" />
<item android:state_focused="true"
android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_disabled_focused_holo_dark" />
<item
android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_disabled_holo_dark" />
</selector>
```

### Lollipop

When I try to apply the same logic to Lollipop, I got stuck:

In styles_material.xml I find the style `<style name="Widget.Material.Button">` where I find the reference to `<item name="background">@drawable/btn_default_material</item>`. But there is no selector??!! Instead I find:

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:color="?attr/colorControlHighlight">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_mtrl_shape" />
</ripple>
```

Could someone please explain, which specific style Lollipop uses for a disabled button.
Thanks a lot!

#### *Edit*

I can partially answer myself: In `@drawable/btn_default_mtrl_shape` I find a reference to `<solid android:color="?attr/colorButtonNormal" />`, which in turn points to `@color/btn_default_material_light`, which includes a selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_enabled="false"
android:alpha="@dimen/disabled_alpha_material_light"
android:color="@color/button_material_light"/>
<item android:color="@color/button_material_light"/>
</selector>
```

But that alpha value only explains half of it. Somehow Lollipop also set the elevation down to 0?

Comment: Elevation isn't part of the background drawable; it's controlled by the stateListAnimator. Take another look at the Material button style.

Answer (score 18):

This is how I resolved this, thanks to your partially answer.

First: add new Folder "color" under "res" folder, if it doesn`t exist.[image]

Add new .xml file in "color" folder (I will call this file ButtonColorSelector.xml) where we will create new [ColorStateList](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList.html) like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="#F2F2F2"/> <!-- disabled -->
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#FF0000"/> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#FF0000"/> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:color="#0000FF"/> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Second: Add that ripple effect .xml file you mentioned, under "drawable" folder and reference your colorSelector instead of btn_default_mtrl_shape. I will call this file RaisedButton.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?attr/colorControlHighlight">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/buttoncolorselector"/>
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

Third: Now you can use your drawable for button background in your layouts, like this:

```
<Button
    android:background="@drawable/raisedbutton"
    android:text="@string/SomeButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="DoStuffitto"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:id="@+id/someButton" />
```